# Using a variable inside a input check in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

The input named `alternativa-***` will have the *** changed in the PHP that comes before. I'm not using a form on PHP only a onClick statement calling the `respondeQuestao` function. But this code seems to not work. Someone have any suggestion.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function respondeQuestao(qid,resposta) {
        var alternativa = document.getElementsByName('input[name = "aternativa-"' + qid ']:checked').value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6;
        if(alternativa==resposta) {
            $("#botao-questao"+qid).hide();
        };
        if(alternativa!=resposta) {

        };
    };
})
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `querySelector()` rather than `getElementsByName()`? Or given that you seem to be using jQuery, why are you not just using `$()` with your selector?

Comment: `input[name = "aternativa-"' + qid ']:checked` is **not** a name. It's a complex selector suited for `.querySelector()` like nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn suggested - And yea... use jQuery

Comment: the name on php is name="alternativa-<?php echo $questao['id'] ?>" I want the java to find this name. So querySelector is the best option?

Comment: @MarccoQuintella java?? - be careful what you wish my little padawan - the Force must you use. Use JavaScript

Comment: huahua i'm very used with PHP but I begun on this JS universe now...

Comment: can you please crate a short snippet that reproduces your problem? Your question is totally vague. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function within the jQuery Ready statement limits the accessibility - define it *outside* of the jQuery Ready statement but call it when you need it.

```
function respondeQuestao(qid, resposta) {
    var alternativa = $("INPUT[name^='alternativa-']:checked").val();
    $("#demo").html(5+6);
    if (alternativa == resposta) {
        $("#botao-questro" + qid).hide()
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

Call the function inside jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    respondeQuestao("id", 11);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: what if those are actual checkboxes? (not radio inputs as you presume)

Comment: OP used `:checked` - could have countered for it, just used what I had :)

Comment: They are ratios, but now when i click the submit button nothing happens